# Boot failure after upgrade /dev/mapper/isw...Volume01 does not exist

Tags: boot, upgrade

I upgraded to 12.04 and now my system won't boot.  It complains about /dev/mapper/isw...Volume01 does not exist and drops me to busybox.

`cat /proc/cmdline` tells me it is indeed trying `Volume01`.

`dmraid -ay` tells me that that the volumes that exist are already active.

I'll try to be as precise as I can so the next guy doesn't get as lost as I did.  I have no idea how to interpret anything and it took me a lot of searching to get this far.

From the Live CD, I could see my drive.  First, I had to open my file browser and click on my drive so that it mounted.  Then I found a script called bootinfoscript (Sorry, I lost the link, LiveCD does not hold bookmarks well).  I downloaded it, and opened another folder (right-click on the folder icon) to my Downloads, double click it to unpack and save in my hard drive's /tmp folder.

Reboot and remove the CD to get back to the BusyBox.

```
mkdir /mnt
mount /dev/mapper/randomNameVolume0p1 /mnt -- I tried all the files here until one worked
mdadm --examine --scan --config=mdadm.con > /mnt/tmp/mdadm.txt
dmraid -r > /mnt/tmp/dmraid.txt
ls -l /dev/mapper > mapper.txt
chroot /mnt
mount /proc
cd /tmp
cat /proc/partitions | strings > partitions.txt
dmesg | grep sd[ab] > dmesg.txt
lshw > lshw.txt
./bootinfoscript
^d
exit
```

Reboot to the LiveCD, open my folder to my hard disk, go to the tmp folder, double click on the txt files I created and copy/paste the info

dmraid.txt

```
/dev/sdb: isw, "isw_bhibhcjiba", GROUP, ok, 976773166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sda: isw, "isw_bhibhcjiba", GROUP, ok, 976773166 sectors, data@ 0
```

mapper.txt

```
crw-------    1   10, 236 control
lrwxrwxrwx    1         7 isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0 -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx    1         7 isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0p5 -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx    1         7 isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0p1 -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx    1         7 isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0p2 -> ../dm-2
```

partitions.txt

```
major minor  #blocks  name
   8        0  488386584 sda
   8       16  488386584 sdb
  11        0    1048575 sr0
 252        0  488383620 dm-0
 252        1  468575856 dm-1
 252        2   19800112 dm-2
 252        3   19800081 dm-3
```

dmesg.txt

```
[    1.331382] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
[    1.331446] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.331449] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.331487] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.373526]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    1.373868] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.142733] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
[    2.142775] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    2.142778] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.142796] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.191869]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 < sdb5 >
[    2.192188] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

lshw.txt

```
_none_
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: System Product Name (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
    vendor: System manufacturer
    version: System Version
    serial: System Serial Number
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.5 dmi-2.5 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To Be Filled By O.E.M. sku=To Be Filled By O.E.M. uuid=A0DF001E-8C00-00C5-D544-E0CB4E54D129
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: P5Q-EM DO
       vendor: ASUSTeK Computer INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev 1.xx
       serial: 103168810001969
       slot: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1102
          date: 05/27/2009
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1984KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q8400  @ 2.66GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q8400 @ 2.66GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: LGA 775
          size: 2666MHz
          capacity: 3800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 333MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 128KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back data
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 4MiB
             capacity: 4MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 37
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
             product: ModulePartNumber00
             vendor: Manufacturer00
             physical id: 0
             serial: SerNum00
             slot: DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: ModulePartNumber01
             vendor: Manufacturer01
             physical id: 1
             serial: SerNum01
             slot: DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
             product: ModulePartNumber02
             vendor: Manufacturer02
             physical id: 2
             serial: SerNum02
             slot: DIMM2
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: ModulePartNumber03
             vendor: Manufacturer03
             physical id: 3
             serial: SerNum03
             slot: DIMM3
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 03
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
           *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: RV710 [Radeon HD 4350]
                vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 00
                size: 256MiB
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: iomemory:d0000000-dfffffff iomemory:fe9e0000-fe9effff ioport:d000(size=256) irq:10
           *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
                description: Audio device
                product: RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
                vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: iomemory:fe9fc000-fe9fffff irq:11
        *-communication UNCLAIMED
             description: Communication controller
             product: 4 Series Chipset HECI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:fe8ff000-fe8ff00f irq:10
        *-network DISABLED
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: eth0
             version: 02
             serial: e0:cb:4e:54:d1:29
             size: 1Gbit/s
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=1.5.1-k duplex=full firmware=0.4-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
             resources: iomemory:fe8c0000-fe8dffff iomemory:fe8fe000-fe8fefff ioport:cc00(size=32) irq:48
        *-usb:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:c480(size=32) irq:16
        *-usb:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:c800(size=32) irq:21
        *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:c880(size=32) irq:18
        *-usb:3 UNCLAIMED
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:fe8fd000-fe8fd3ff irq:18
        *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
             description: Audio device
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:fe8f4000-fe8f7fff irq:3
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
           *-ide UNCLAIMED
                description: IDE interface
                product: 88SE6101/6102 single-port PATA133 interface
                vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: c0
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: ide pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: ioport:ec00(size=8) ioport:e880(size=4) ioport:e800(size=8) ioport:e480(size=4) ioport:e400(size=16) iomemory:feaff000-feaff1ff irq:16
        *-usb:4 UNCLAIMED
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:c000(size=32) irq:23
        *-usb:5 UNCLAIMED
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:c080(size=32) irq:19
        *-usb:6 UNCLAIMED
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:c400(size=32) irq:18
        *-usb:7 UNCLAIMED
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:fe8fc000-fe8fc3ff irq:23
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: a2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
           *-firewire UNCLAIMED
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: FW322/323
                vendor: LSI Corporation
                physical id: 3
                bus info: pci@0000:04:03.0
                version: 70
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=64 maxlatency=24 mingnt=12
                resources: iomemory:febff000-febfffff irq:19
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82801JDO (ICH10DO) LPC Interface Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-storage
             description: RAID bus controller
             product: 82801 SATA Controller [RAID mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             logical name: scsi2
             logical name: scsi4
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:b880(size=8) ioport:b800(size=4) ioport:b480(size=8) ioport:b400(size=4) ioport:b080(size=32) iomemory:fe8f2000-fe8f27ff irq:47
           *-disk:0 UNCLAIMED
                description: ATA Disk
                product: WDC WD5000AAKS-0
                vendor: Western Digital
                physical id: 0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                version: 05.0
                serial: WD-WCAWF2891700
                configuration: ansiversion=5
           *-disk:1 UNCLAIMED
                description: ATA Disk
                product: WDC WD5000AAKS-0
                vendor: Western Digital
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
                version: 05.0
                serial: WD-WCAWF2839960
                configuration: ansiversion=5
           *-cdrom UNCLAIMED
                description: SCSI CD-ROM
                product: iHAS124   Y
                vendor: ATAPI
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
                version: BL0V
                capabilities: removable
                configuration: ansiversion=5
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:fe8f3000-fe8f30ff ioport:400(size=32) irq:15
  *-battery
       description: Nickel Cadmium Battery
       product: Nikon Ultra Plus
       vendor: Nikon Battery
       physical id: 1
       version: 08/11/97
       serial: NI00123
       slot: Left side of System
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       physical id: 2
       version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       capacity: 32768mWh
```

RESULTS.txt

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================


============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

no valid partition table found
"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL


================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume01 /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr)
/dev/shm         /run/shm                 none       (rw,bind)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

ERROR: mkdir /var/lock/dmraid
ERROR: mkdir /var/lock/dmraid
ERROR: mkdir /var/lock/dmraid
  /var/lock/lvm: mkdir failed: No such file or directory
  File-based locking initialisation failed.
mdadm: Devices UUID-ad6f745e:e3ae0039:235d131b:a9b94c7c and UUID-ad6f745e:e3ae0039:235d131b:a9b94c7c have the same name: /dev/md/Volume0
mdadm: Duplicate MD device names in conf file were found.
cat: /tmp/BootInfo-n8B9zWVa/BLKID_summary: No such file or directory
```

it had some errors, so I re-ran it from xterm inside the Live CD.
RESULTS.txt

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub Legacy (v0.97) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks on the 
    same drive in partition #1 for /boot/grub/stage2 and /boot/grub/menu.lst.
 => Grub Legacy (v0.97) is installed in the MBR of 
    /dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0 and looks on the same drive in 
    partition #1 for /boot/grub/stage2 and /boot/grub/menu.lst.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume01: _______________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume02: _______________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume05: _______________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                  63   937,151,774   937,151,712  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         937,151,775   976,751,999    39,600,225   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         937,151,838   976,751,999    39,600,162  82 Linux swap / Solaris


Drive: isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0 _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0: 500.1 GB, 500104826880 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60800 cylinders, total 976767240 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume01                 63   937,151,774   937,151,712  83 Linux
/dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume02        937,151,775   976,751,999    39,600,225   5 Extended
/dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume05        937,151,838   976,751,999    39,600,162  82 Linux swap / Solaris


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0p1 e18d4cf9-3acc-4d67-92aa-1602b2dba3fb   ext4       
/dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0p5 15675782-b581-4ce8-8dd6-419cfb0a30ca   swap       
/dev/sda                                                isw_raid_member 
/dev/sdb                                                isw_raid_member 
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS i386

========================= "ls -R /dev/mapper/" output: =========================

/dev/mapper:
control
isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0
isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0p1
isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0p2
isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0p5

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume0p1 /media/e18d4cf9-3acc-4d67-92aa-1602b2dba3fb ext4       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda1


Unknown BootLoader on sda2


Unknown BootLoader on sda5


Unknown BootLoader on isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume01


Unknown BootLoader on isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume02


Unknown BootLoader on isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume05



=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

hexdump: /dev/sda1: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/sda1: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/sda2: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/sda2: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/sda5: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/sda5: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume01: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume01: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume02: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume02: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume05: No such file or directory
hexdump: /dev/mapper/isw_bhibhcjiba_Volume05: No such file or directory
```

I'm still stuck.  I still have no idea what to do.  Hopefully, someone who does will see this and give me a clue.

Answer (score 1):

The name ...Volume01 was invalid, and it is now correctly being recognized as ...Volume1p1, but your system is still referring to the old name.  If you had been using UUIDs to refer to your filesystem this would not have happened.  You should be able to press the `e` key at the grub meu to edit the command, and insert the `p` before the partition number in the kernel root argument to boot, then you will want to update your /etc/fstab to either also insert the `p` or switch it to use the UUID instead, then run `update-grub`.

Comment: Pressing Esc while grub was loading and editing from the menu didn't work for me.  I could make the change, but couldn't figure out how to save the changes.  Instead, from busybox, I mounted the drive drive and chrooted (as in my original post), then edited (pico /boot/grub/menu.lst).  Made the changes.  Did he same for /etc/fstab, then ran grub-install.  Rebooted and it looks like it worked.  :)  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @NibbleAbit, `/boot/grub/menu.lst` means you are still using grub legacy, which was abandoned years ago and Ubuntu switched to grub2 in 9.10.  You should upgrade to grub2.  I also noticed you don't appear to have any windows partitions.  If you don't have to dual boot with windows, it is best to avoid fakeraids, and stick to pure `mdadm` software raid instead.  See http://wiki.ubuntu.com/FakeRaidHowto for more information on fakeraid.